# Laravel file manager routes not working

Tags: php, laravel, tinymce

I'm using [Laravel File Manager](https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-filemanager) in a TinyMCE editor. It produces image tags like this:

```
<img src="/laravel-filemanager/photos/shares/test.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="100" />
```

On my localhost these work. On the production server they do not. The `laravel-filemanager` portion of the URL refers to routes which are set up by the package. But those routes do not actually appear in any of the routes files in my `routes` folder. I'm less puzzled about why it's not working on the production server than why it *is* working on my local server.

Comment: Is it possible you've published the package config file on your development machine but not on the production server? There is a prefix settings for routing: http://unisharp.github.io/laravel-filemanager/config

Comment: Due to absurd client stipulations I'm FTP'ing the whole lot to shared hosting, so the entire codebase should be identical.

Answer (score 0):

Try if these commands helps you :

`php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:clear`